# How to set a window title in Italic format

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I want to set window title in normal + Italic format
like this

```
w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
w.setTitle(“AAAAAA– BBBBBB”)
```

The first part AAAAAA must be displayed in normal way and secon part BBBBBB should be diplayed in bold and Italic format.

I created that string in MS word and copy pasted in a.py file but i get below error

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x96' in a.py , but no encoding declared

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your error is from smart quotes `“`, you need to replace these with the normal `"` quote character.

The title bar of your application is not controlled by QT, it is the responsibility of the [window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager); so you cannot make the title bold or italic from within your application.